# Piping iostat -d 1 to python sys.stdin

Tags: python, terminal, pipe, iostat

I am trying to pipe the output of utilities like iostat, mongostat, etc with the command:

```
$ iostat -d 1 | ./script.py
```

in which I am using the code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

I see that it hangs and does not print each line to the console.
if I run without the flag to repeat every second '-d 1' where output only happens once, the script behaves as expected.

$ iostat | ./script.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being buffered, you can call `iter` on `sys.stdout.readline`:

```
import sys
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline,""):
    print line
```

Running `iostat` on it's own just outputs a few lines, `iostat -d 1` loops continuously so the data gets buffered.

Comment: Thank you Padriac, this is also be the same situation with Popen from subprocess if it helps anyone. iter(p.stdin.readline,""):

Comment: @BobR, no worries, yes, it's a specific issue related to python2,  ``for line in sys.stdin:` using python3 would work just fine